# Drawing a filled circle in python

Tags: python, draw, geometry

I need to know how to make a filled circle.
i Have a hollow circle now but i need it to be filled.
I can not figure out how to do that.
does someone know how to make from this a filled circle.
also i'm bound by conditions.

Allowed keywords, operators, etc. are: if, elif, else, while, for … in range, =, variables, values, **, *, /, +, -, %, math.sqrt(), and, or, not, ==, !=, <, <=, >, >=, +=,  def and return

However, you are not allowed to use the *-operator on string and int. So for example ''***'' * 3 is not allowed, but 3 * 4 is
there is a abs function and a join line function in there does someone know a alternative for that?

```
width, height = 11, 11
a, b = 5, 5
r = 5
EPSILON = 2.2

map_= [[' ' for x in range(width)]for y in range(height)]

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if abs((x-a)**2 + (y-b)**2 - r**2) < EPSILON**2:
            map_[y][x] = "#"
for line in map_:
    print ' '.join(line)
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost got it right. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
width, height = 11, 11
a, b = 5, 5
r = 5
EPSILON = 2.2

map_= [[' ' for x in range(width)]for y in range(height)]

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if (x-a)**2 + (y-b)**2 <= (r**2 - EPSILON**2):
            map_[y][x] = "#"
for line in map_:
    print(' '.join(line))
```

Goodluck!

Comment: o sorry  i forgot to ask in my question i also need to users to be able to input a sice and then i should scale to that number. Also do you know a another option for the .join(line)) function? i'm not allowed to use that one

Comment: oeps wasn't finischt yet i'm not sure abou the .join(line) function I;m not sure i'm allowed to use that one.   It says oparators and keywords is.   function options are not the same as keywords or oparators right?    so i could use that function?

Answer (score 1):

Crazy way (find index of first occurence and last occurence and fill list with `#` between these elements:

```
def first_occ(l):
    return l.index('#')

def last_occ(l):
    return len(l) - 1 - l[::-1].index('#')

for i, el in enumerate(map_):
    map_[i][first_occ(el):last_occ(el)] = ['#'] * (last_occ(el) - first_occ(el))

for line in map_:
    print ' '.join(line)
```

`*` Yes and this does not satisfy to your restrictions.

```
      # # # # #
    # # # # # # #
  # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # #
  # # # # # # # # #
    # # # # # # #
      # # # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditional so that it accepts all coordinates whose distance to the center is less than or equal to the radius.

```
if (x-a)**2 + (y-b)**2 <= r**2:
```